# Was this site conceived implicitly for the Gnome/Unity desktop environment?

Tags: discussion, scope

And adjacently: is there an intention to organize this site in different subcategories for the different members/desktop environments of the Ubuntu family?

Comment: This site is organized into different subcategories already...[using tags.](http://askubuntu.com/tags)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask Ubuntu gives support for any of the Ubuntu family releases, not only Unity or GNOME. Questions regarding Lubuntu, Xubuntu and Kubuntu are more than welcome and there are plenty out there already.

There is no intent to split the site to cover these releases separately, only that most users will be using the default Unity release. Tags are used to separate the different DEs, ie: [kde](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kde), [kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kubuntu), [xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce) [xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xubuntu).

Please read the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) for more information on what belongs or not in Ask Ubuntu.